# How can you use conditional expectation to find a distribution?

Tags: probability

The problem I need to solve is the following but a general idea or another example is enough. 
X and Y have standard normal distribution and are independent, prove tha X/Y have cauchy distribution.

Comment: Getting you started: $P(X/Y \leq z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X/Y \leq z \mid Y=y) dP(Y=y)$. The conditioning is basically trivial given how $X/Y$ depends on $Y$, you get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X/y \leq z) dP(Y=y)$. Now split the domain up to get $\int_{-\infty}^0 P(X \geq zy) dP(Y=y) + \int_0^\infty P(X \leq zy) dP(Y=y)$. Then $dP(Y=y)$ is the same as $f_Y(y) dy$. So now you have some calculus to do...

Comment: "Conditional expectation", whatever that means, is offtopic if one wants "to find (the desired) distribution".

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, always go back to the cumulative dprobability functions to make concepts clearer.

If a random variable has distribution $f$ then 
$$
P(X < \eta) = \int_{x=-\infty}^{\eta}f(x)dx
$$
The following sketch plays fast and loose with positive versus negative values of the variables; to do this right you have to break things up into 2 or 4 cases.

If two independent variables have distribution $f$ then
$$
P(X/Y < \eta) = \int dx f(x) P  \left(y < \frac{x}{\eta} \right)
$$
and this becomes 
$$
F(\eta) \equiv P(X/Y < \eta) = \int dx f(x)  \int_{u=-\infty}^{x/\eta}f(u)du
$$
The integral would be difficult.  However, to get $f(\eta)$ you will need in the end to take the  derivative with respect to $\eta$ to get $f(\eta)$, and it should be possible to make things easier by differating under the integral sign.

Comment: How do you get to the second ecuation?